# How to properly integrate Google Analytics in FB Instant Articles?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics, facebook-instant-articles

I am running [Instant Articles For WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fb-instant-articles/) on my Wordpress site, at the moment all the traffic coming from Instant Articles isn't registering in Google Analytics.

I did a little research and found that [facebook allows the additional of 3rd party  tracking codes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/analytics/).

I'm using the new gTag.js instead of the old method.

This is code is placed before `</head>`

```
<!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-MY-ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-MY-ID');
</script>
```

And this is the code in `Instant Articles` Wordpress plugin, in the "Embed Custom Code" section.

```
<figure class="op-tracker">
    <iframe>

        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-MY-ID"></script>
        <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());

            gtag('create', 'UA-MY-ID', 'auto');
            gtag('require', 'displayfeatures');
            gtag('set', 'campaignSource', 'Facebook');
            gtag('set', 'campaignMedium', 'Instant Article');
            gtag('set', 'page_title', 'Instant Articles: '+ia_document.title);
            gtag('send', 'pageview');

            gtag('config', 'UA-MY-ID');
        </script>

    </iframe>
</figure>
```

Yet, I still don't see any campaigns being created in my analytics dashboard. I don't see the traffic coming from Instant Articles at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed. I removed the HTML tags and fixed the parameters of `ga` to the following

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-MY-ID', 'auto');
  ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'Facebook');
  ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'Facebook Instant Articles');
  ga('set', 'referrer', ia_document.referrer);
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```